# Aiopg use pool connection

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am bit confusion about how to use connection poll in `aiopg` right.

Should I call `async with db.acquire() as conn:` every time before request or may just one call `acquire`?

For example, I have some enpoint that makes a few query in database (without transaction). Let's say there are two ways:

  1.

```py
async def request_handle(request):
    db = request.config_dict['db']  # db is Engine
    async with db.acquire() as conn:
        await query_1(conn)
        await query_2(conn)
        await query_3(conn)
```

  2.

```py
async def request_handle(request):
    db = request.config_dict['db']  # db is Engine
    await query_1(db)
    await query_2(db)
    await query_3(db)
```

In way 2 in each function call `async with db.acquire() as conn:`

In aiopg's source I saw settings that called `max_size` does it mean max size of pool connections count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for first approach since, it's always better to reuse a connection as it's quite heavyweight. E.g. take a look at [this example](https://aiopg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#complex-sqlalchemy-queries) from aiopg docs, connection is being reused. This is a good practice in general, not specifically related to async programming.

As to `async with db.acquire()`, it is asynchronous context manager, meaning coroutine can give up contol entering and exiting a block below it. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with

Another thing is that you want `await query_1(db)` instead of  `async query_1(db)`. `query_1` should be defined as `async def` keyword and use async versions of `execute`.

Comment: Of course, await..it's my fault. So follow to first example is better? On every http request I once acquire connection and use it during all request?